# Do a Lookup through an IP Range C#

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a project that uses TCP/IP as communication with equipment in which each equipment has its own IP and I can search for them through that IP and port where they are located, which obviously returns the equipment which the IP and port that was informed, but would I be able to search all equipment at once through the IP range? Or would there be another way to locate them all at once? Not to be locating one at a time.

Comment: What does "search through that IP" mean? You ping that IP?

Comment: TCP is for endpoint-to-endpoint communication. You will not be able to connect to an entire IP range at once.

Depending on your equipment, it may support a service discovery protocol such as LLDP, and be discoverable that way.

If your IP range is small enough, you could brute-force this by opening a connection to all IPs in the range in parallel, and waiting to see which ones respond. You might narrow the possibilities by pinging first to see which are responsive, if your equipment supports it.